# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Unable to pull app to device using MTWW

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ios7.1, worklight-mtww

First off let me be clear. I have several iOS devices. On the devices that have 7.0.6 I have no issues. When I updated one of the devices to 7.1 I'm having an issue. Let me explain.

On the iOS device that has 7.1 I navigate to the workbench URL and then I go to Manage applications and select install. I then get this message "Cannot install applications because the certificate for >ip address< is not vald. This process works on devices that have 7.0.6. I'm assuming there are issues with the new iOS update.

Now I did some searching and I found something that said there's an issue when trying to download an app from a HTTP site, so I changed a Web Reports setting (found in Eclipse Preferences -> Test -> Performance Test Reports -> Web Reports) to "Security is required to access reports". Thus it changed the port number to "8443". I then navigate back to the workbench URL using the https : // ip:port and try to install the app again. This time it just says Cannot open.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: After updating my MTWW to 6.1.0.1 I'm still having the issue above...

Comment: MTWW in Worklight 6.1.0.1 does not support iOS 7.1, as stated multiple times in this question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround to be able to test with iOS 7.1

1) Get the zip of instrumented Application from developer or other who can run rtwBuildXcode.sh on a Mac and who has the source code for Application. [RmotXXXXXXXX.zip file]

2) Use RTWec "Add Application to list..." button and brows to the zip to "import" it into RTWec.

3) UnZip the zip and use iTunes (for Windows) "Add File to Library..." menu to navigate in zip folder to the instrumented iOS Device application [XXXXXXXX.ipa in “instrumented/iOS Device” folder]

4) Plug in iDevice to Windows using USB, select the App, click associated "Install" button, then "Sync" iTunes.

5) Now test as usual...

Thanks

Comment: The update didn't fix my original issue. The above is really unacceptable in an enterprise environment.

Comment: This is the current solution until support is added.

Answer (score 0):

MTWW in Worklight 6.1.0.0 and 6.1.0.1 (to be released, soon) does not support iOS 7.1.
Work is under way to provide support in a future release of Worklight.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Do you have a release date?

Comment: Not at this time, no. If you are an IBM customer, you can talk about this with your IBM contact person.

Comment: Of course it's not working, read again what I wrote - MTWW in Worklight 6.0.0.x and 6.1.0.1 does not support iOS 7.1, so of course it won't work. There is a workaround. See the answer by dom.

Comment: That's funny because I have an email from a person at IBM saying something different...

Comment: I don't know who you are talking to. The above is the way things are. There is the workaround provided by dom and work is under way to add support. That's final.