# Cannot install applications because the certificate is not valid in iOS10.3.3 with MobileFIrst 8.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

I'm getting this error when try to install an apps from the IBM App Centre.

[image]

I found the similar question and try the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22601154/getting-cannot-install-applications-because-the-certificate-is-not-valid-error)
but none of the solution work for my situation.

I'm just migration from mobileFirst 7.1 to MobileFirst 8.0
there is already a certificate in the server, and using https to login to the IBM app center.

I can successfully login and view the apps in the IBM Apps center, just don't know why it hit error when i try to install.

Any idea ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Was IBM AppCenter 7.1 working fine with HTTPs on the same device? Did anything else change?

Comment: it was working fine when connect to the MFP7.1 server using the same device(same IBM AppCenter), but it fail to install an apps when i connect to MFP8.0 server

Answer (score 0):

Is it a valid certificate ?. If not then if its a self signed certificate that your are using then it must be a CA certificate, that is, it must have the X509 extension named BasicConstraint set to CA:TRUE

Please refer the below links:

[Managing and installing self-signed CA certificates in an Application Center test environment](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/appcenter/t_ac_ssca_certs_testenv.html)

[Installing and configuring the IBM MobileFirst Foundation Application Center](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/installation-configuration/production/appcenter/#managing-and-installing-self-signed-ca-certificates-in-an-application-center-test-environment)